# Transversal intersection of complex projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex projective varieties, which intersect transversally at $x$. We can also think of X and Y as smooth manifolds. Now when considered as smooth manifolds do they intersect transversally at $x$.?
It might be a trivial question but I have no idea how to proceed with this question.

Comment: What do you expect, except that the usual definition also apply, i.e you need $T_xX + T_xY \to T_x \Bbb P^n$ to be surjective.

Comment: i expect the usual definition.

Comment: Ah wait I'm sorry, I misread the question. I understand it now. The answer is yes. To see this, show that if $z \in T_x \Bbb P^n$ is in the image, then the $\mathfrak R(z)$ and $\text{Im}(z)$ are in the image of the corresponding map of real vector space.

Comment: i don't follow what image you are talking?

Comment: If I understand correctly now, you just want to know is a surjection of complex holomorphic vector bundles induces a surjection of the underlying real vector bundles ? Then the answer is yes, and it's just linear algebra. Or maybe I mistunderstood your question again ...

Comment: first i treat X and Y as projective varieties in Zariski topology and then as real manifolds

Comment: I see, so you need to check that 1) the holomorphic tangent bundle coincide with the Zariski tangent space $Hom_k(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2,k)$ (I think you need Hadamard lemma). 2) Then you use that a surjection of complex vector bundle induces a surjection of the underlying real vector bundles.

Comment: I have no knowledge of complex manifolds, so i think i don't follow your comment,

Comment: Could you write your definition of transversal intersection of complex algebraic varieties ?

Comment: $T_xX+T_xY=T_x\mathcal\{P}^N\$ where the tangent spaces are zariski tangent spaces

Comment: And what is your definition of $T_xX$ algebraically ?

Comment: Zariski tanngent space at that point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80112/discussion-between-user345777-and-nicolas-hemelsoet).